# is ssl certificate encoded?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My application capture every packet coming from the server. I can read those packet for HTTP. I want to read the subject field from ssl certificate. But I cant. Is it encoded? If it is, how can I decode & read it?

Comment: What do you mean with "the subject field from ssl certificate"?

Comment: @arkasha: I suspect he means [the Subject field from the ssl certificate](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6).

Comment: Actually, I want to extract domain name from common name(CN) which is placed in subject field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SSL negotiates a protocol that needs certificates, the certificates are generally in [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) based [X.509v3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) format when they're sent from the server to the client.

From the [TLS 1.0 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) (which is a start if you want to listen to/analyze the protocol);

> **7.4.2. Server certificate**
>
> **When this message will be sent:**
>          The server must send a certificate whenever the agreed-upon key
>          exchange method is not an anonymous one. This message will always
>          immediately follow the server hello message.
>
> **Meaning of this message:**
>          The certificate type must be appropriate for the selected cipher
>          suite's key exchange algorithm, and *is generally an X.509v3
>          certificate.*